# Subsection Numbering using LaTeXbangla

Tags: sectioning, numbering, indic, subsection

I'm using [LaTeXbangla](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexbangla)to write in Bengali/Bangla. I'd like the Section and Subsection numbering to appear as [১] [১.১], but instead they are surfacing as [১.] for both, with the only difference between section and subsection being their size. How can I (1) remove the period at the end of the section number (without using feature=0 since I like some of the other functionalities) and (2) make the section number appear before the subsection number? The style that I'm trying to emulate using Arabic numerals is below:

```
\documentclass[18pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush,
banglattfont=Siyam Rupali
]{latexbangla}
\begin{document}
\section{উচ্চারণ}
\subsection{ব্যঞ্জনধ্বনি}
```

[image: Using LaTeXbangla]

[image: Using Arabic Numerals, no LaTeXbangla. This is what I want to emulate using Bangla numerals]

Answer (score 1):

[image: bangla title]

`latexbangla.sty` imports many packages, and formats the titles using `titlesec` package with this command:

```
    %adding a dot after the number in titles
    \titlelabel{\thetitle.\enspace}
```

Try putting this redefinition in your preamble:

```
\titlelabel{[\thetitle]\enspace}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Bengali,changecounternumbering=true]{bengali}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont{Noto Sans Bengali}[Script=Bengali,Renderer=HarfBuzz]
\usepackage{titlesec}

%%from latexbangla.sty, line 176
%   %adding a dot after the number in titles
%   \titlelabel{\thetitle.\enspace}

\titlelabel{[\thetitle]\enspace}
    
\begin{document}
\section{উচ্চারণ}
\subsection{ব্যঞ্জনধ্বনি}
\end{document}
```

I don't have your fonts. The code compiles with either xelatex or lualatex.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\banglasection` and `\banglatext` commands from package `bangla`

```
\documentclass[18pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{bangla}

\banglasection

\begin{document}
\section{\banglatext{উচ্চারণ}}
\subsection{\banglatext{ব্যঞ্জনধ্বনি}}
\end{document}
```

[image]